# How does one tune down to 40 cents with a snark tuner?

Tags: tuning, tuner

I am trying to play along to

and standard tuning isn't quite matching up... so it must be down tuned a bit, but how much? I have the Snark SN-8 Super Tight All Instrument Tuner and I haven't used it to its full extent yet

Comment: Not being flippant. Try adjusting the guitar's tuning by ear. You could get pretty quick and good at it. It's not that big a deal. But - you've bought the gismo, and want to use it. Understandable. Learn to do it by ear, and people will be well impressed ! Comment, not answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here are two methods to match your guitar to the video: one way with the tuner (using the 40-cent adjustment cited in the OP) and one without the tuner.

#### Recalibrating the tuner

According to the [SN-8 user manual](http://www.snarktuners.com/wp-content/pdf-manuals/SN8-revised.pdf), to change the pitch calibration, one should

> push the round "PITCH CAL" button on the back side of the tuner and immediately press either the up or down triangular buttons to choose a new tuning reference. The pitch reference can be set anywhere from 415 - 466Hz. Pressing the power switch on the front of the tuner resets the tuner to A-440.

Tuning 440Hz down by 40 cents gives gives 430Hz.

[image: Image of Hertz calculation]
([SOURCE](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-centsratio.htm))

#### Not using the tuner

Tune any of the pitches you're certain of against the recording, preferably an open string. Then tune the rest of the guitar from there.

Comment: Back in the '60s not using a tuner was the preferred method - in fact, the only method. Playing along to stuff on the radio necessitated changing tuning every few songs. Got very quick at it.